# ag-grid (React) having custom column for exports

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

Say I have the following data:

```
[
  { name: 'Cesar', date: '2023-10-10 05:10AM' },
  { name: 'James', date: '2023-10-11 10:10AM' }
]
```

and I have the following `columnDefs` for ag-grid:

```
[
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name' },
  { headerName: 'Date', field: 'date' }
]
```

If I export it (CSV or Excel) I get the same exact 2 columns, which is the default behavior.

But, how can I have the export functionality (CSV and Excel) to split the date column into two columns? This is the data structure we expect to see in the exported files.

```
| Name  | Date       | Time    |
| ----- | ---------- | ------- |
| Cesar | 2023-10-10 | 05:10AM |
| James | 2023-10-11 | 10:10AM |
```

#### Things I've tried

1. `processCellCallback` and `processHeaderCallback` to split the `date` column into 2 columns; but the "2 columns" are rendered in the same column

[two columns in one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLRvB.png)

2. I tried adding a third column to my `columnDefs` which is `hide: true` and `lockVisible: true`:

```
[
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name' },
  { headerName: 'Date', field: 'date' }, 
  { headerName: 'Time', field: 'date', hide: true, lockVisible: true } // with the right getter
]
```

This works partially because the column shows up in the Column Menu columnsMenuTab
[column showing in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8eIs.png)

The checkbox is disabled, so the column cannot be shown ever; but we need the "time" column to be *only available* on the exported files, not in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats! You're very close to solve this puzzle.

> **suppressColumnsToolPanel**
>
> Set to true if you do not want this column or group to appear in the
> Columns Tool Panel.

```
{ 
  headerName: "Time", 
  field: 'date', 
  hide: true, 
  suppressColumnsToolPanel: true // this one
}
```

Here's an example

[image: Example]

https://plnkr.co/plunk/UWTdLRgBM5H9ooLh